# Как мне доделать свой параллакс слайдер?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот фидла http://jsfiddle.net/M4t4L/ , здесь не проигрывается анимация при переходе на последний слайд, вернее не на последний, а на первый, когда все слайды заканчиваются и ты переключаешься на первый, тогда и не проигрывается анимация и я не знаю как реализовать из этих данных функции prev next, нужно ваша помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно двигать сами картинки, вместо указателя на них:

```
$("#trigger").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);

    i++;
    if (i >= count) {
        i = 0;
    }
    j++;
    if (j >= count) {
        j = 0;
    }

    container.find("li")
        .finish()
        .removeClass('active')
        .eq(2) /показываем 3ю картинку, если надо будет крутить назад, то надо как минимум 4 картинки
        .width(0)
        .addClass("active")
        .animate({
            "width": "100%"
        }, 400,
        function () {
            container.find("li").first().appendTo(container); //первую в конец, если надо назад крутить, то последнюю в начало
        });
});
```

Дополнительно я убрал блокировку переключател во время анимации, т.к. блокировка ui анимацией - раздражает.

http://jsfiddle.net/M4t4L/3/